Remove objects from an array list in PowerShell not working
I am trying to remove id's contained in one ArrayList out of another ArrayList. However, the values are not getting removed.
My code:
    # SQL Query to get all the users that have the admin role.
    $userDetailsQuery = "   SELECT PortalUserID
                            FROM User
                            WHERE RoleID = 7 "
                
    $usersWithRoleX = Invoke-SqlCmd -ConnectionString $connectionString -Query $userDetailsQuery
    
        foreach ($value in $usersWithRoleX){

            # SQL Query to get all the users with admin role that have the extender role too.
            $checkUserHasRoleQuery = "  SELECT PortalUserID
                                        FROM User
                                        WHERE  PortalUserID = $($value.PortalUserID)
                                        AND RoleID = 88 "

            $usersWithRoleY = Invoke-SqlCmd -ConnectionString $connectionString -Query $checkUserHasRoleQuery   

# Remove id's contained in ArrayList2 out of ArrayList1, so that I am left with all the users that have RoleID = 7, but don't have RoleID = 88.
            [System.Collections.ArrayList]$ArrayList1 = $usersWithRoleX
            [System.Collections.ArrayList]$ArrayList2 = $usersWithRoleY

            $ArrayList1.Remove($ArrayList2)     

        }

$usersWithRoleX and $usersWithRoleY are type Object[], I then convert them into ArrayLists.
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object

Array: $usersWithRoleX
PortalUserID
------------
          29
         145
         317
         439
         499
         540
         626

Array: $usersWithRoleY
PortalUserID
------------
         439
         499

I expected the outcome of $ArrayList1 to be:
PortalUserID
------------
          29
         145
         317
         540
         626

Please can you advise how I get an ArrayList with the values removed.

Appart from the important remark "We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic List<T> class. The ArrayList class is designed to hold heterogeneous collections of objects. However, it does not always offer the best performance. Instead, we recommend the following...", the Remove() method doesn't support to remove multiple items in once meanimg that you have to interate throught one list and remove the concerned items from the other.

For alternatives see: Comparing two arrays & get the values which are not common

You are misunderstanding .Remove().
It only removes the element equal to the one you pass.
None of the elements in $ArrayList1 is a array itself, so none gets removed.
To get what you want you need to filter the original collection into a new collection without the elements found in the second collection.
Also: you might want to use [Lists] instead of [ArrayList]: for all purposes and intents [List] are better than [ArrayList] at everything.
So, an example:
[System.Collections.Generic.List[pscustomobject]]$FilteredCollection = $usersWithRoleX | 
    Where-Object -Property PortalUserID -NotIn $usersWithRoleY.PortalUserID

If you do not plan to add or remove elements from the reuslting collection, feel free to remove [System.Collections.Generic.List[pscustomobject]]: it will instead become a simple array which is fine and dandy when it's about read-only stuff

Thank you.
However, the original collection still has the elements found in the second collection.
`
Get all the users that have the admin role.
$usersWithRoleX = Invoke-SqlCmd -ConnectionString $connectionString -Query $usersWithRoleXQuery
foreach ($value in $usersWithRoleX ){
SQL get all users with admin and extender role.
$usersWithRoleY = Invoke-SqlCmd -ConnectionString $connectionString -Query $usersWithRoleYQuery
$FilteredCollection = $usersWithRoleX |
Where-Object -Property PortalUserID -NotIn $usersWithRoleY.PortalUserID
}
$FilteredCollection`

@Stacker01 - The code in your comment above doesn`t match your original post, could you add the actual code to your question. I think your use of foreach may be extraneous.

@Doofus I've updated the post. Thank you.

Of course the original collection has still all the elements: I'm passing them to a new variable to so keep things easier to read. Just replace $FilteredCollection = $usersWithRoleX with $usersWithRoleX = $usersWithRoleX.
On a side note wouldn't simply use SELECT PortalUserID FROM User WHERE RoleID = 7 and RoleID != 88 be faster?

@sirtao that's done the job, thank you for your input!
